# C# console exe program which create named argument

Tags: c#

If suppose I am going to create an exe c# console program, and I would like to do something like

```
testing.exe /a input1 /b input2 .... etc ..
```

are their any sample code for doing that?

Comment: do you mean like storing input from the console as a variable?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to take a look at the library  https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

This gives you lots of options and should support your needs.

Here is a tutorial to explain the library

https://codingblog.carterdan.net/2019/04/12/command-line-parser/

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the links for reference.